# echo $HISTSIZE not printing when executed via shell script but works in command line

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, command-history, echo

I created a shell script file named 1.sh with only one echo command:

```
echo $HISTSIZE
```

I made the file 1.sh executable and tried to run the file in the terminal by running the command

```
./1.sh
```

It printed an empty line on the terminal.
But when I run this command at the shell prompt I get 1000 as output.

Why is the echo not working in my shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You script is running in a non-interactive shell, which has history disabled by default (assuming it supports history, but that’s the case in most `sh` implementations nowadays); thus `HISTSIZE` is empty.

If you forcibly enable history (in Bash at least), you’ll get the default value:

```
set -o history
echo $HISTSIZE
```

Comment: But i have a query. When i just echo $HISTSIZE in commandline ,i get a value 1000. But when i does it by enabling history in shell script, i get a value 500. Why there is a difference in two values?

Comment: You get different values because, when the shell runs a script, it doesn’t process your startup scripts (`.profile`, `.bashrc` etc.). Thus `HISTSIZE` is set to the default value, 500, rather than the value your startup scripts set, 1000.